# Error: for-each not applicable to expression type

Tags: java

So I have a problem with my code. It says I require an array or java.lang.Iterable. I tried to fix but it took too many hours without any success. How can I fix it

```
package PowerSystem;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import static PowerSystem.Main.*;

public class Utils {

    private static Logger logger = Main.getPluginLogger();

    public static void log(String messages) {
        for (String message : messages) {
            logger.info(message);
        }
    }

    // omitted the other examples, because it's
    // essentially the same issue everywhere

}
```

Comment: What output do you expect? If `messages = "this is a message"`, what should the for loop do?

Comment: Shouldn't those methods accept an **array** of `String`s instead of a `String`?

Comment: ... or some kind of `Iterable<String>` or a `String`-varargs...

Comment: String is not an interable object. This would only make sense if the `log` method took a string list as a parameter. Something like:
`public static void log(List<String> messages){
...
}`

Answer (score 1):

Split your "messages" input into a collection of individual messages.  If you have a delimiter in the "messages" string, you could add..
String[] messageArray = messages.split("delimiterHere");

to the beginning of your methods.

Bottom line, String is not a collection of Strings

Answer (score -3):

Change
for (String message : messages) {
into
for (String message : messages.to_char_array() ) {

Comment: 1. Please format your code. 2. `to_char_array` is wrong. 3. `String message : messages.toCharArray()` would still be wrong